# Discord.py send() takes 1 to 2 positional arguments

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to code a voting system with discord.py I wanted the bot to send the message which the user sent before I already found out I can do this by coding `async def voting(ctx, *text):` and put the * symbol in front of the text argument but when I try to code the bot so that he sends the text argument the error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 6 were given

appears in the console. I already tried things like putting it in a f-string but it won't work.

Here's the full code of this command

```
@client.command()
async def voting(ctx, *text):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    message = await ctx.send(*text)

    cross = client.get_emoji(790243377953636372)
    check = client.get_emoji(790243459050110977)
    voting_cross = 0
    voting_check = 0

    await client.add_reaction(message, emoji = cross)
    await client.add_reaction( emoji = check )

    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

        reaction_channel = reaction.message.channel
        voting_channel = client.get_channel(voting_channel_id)

        if reaction_channel == voting_channel :

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":

                voting_check = voting_check + 1
                print(f'{user} has votet with ')

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "❌":

                voting_cross = voting_cross + 1
                print(f'{user} has votet with ')

    @client.command()
    async def results(ctx):

        if voting_check > voting_cross :
            await ctx.send(f'More people votet for :greencheckmark: ({voting_check} votes)')

        else :
            await ctx.send(f'More people votet for :redcross: ({voting_cross} votes)')
```

Comment: Are you sure `*text` is not represent more than 2 arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is really bad.

1. You're unpacking a list, not joining it

```py
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(lst)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*lst)
1 2 3 # It's not the same, you need to join it using str.join(list)
>>> ' '.join(lst)
'1 2 3'
```

Also if you want to pass it already as a string use this:

```py
@client.command()
async def voting(ctx, *, text):
```

2. `client.add_reaction` it's not a thing anymore, if you're using `discord.py 1.0+` it's `Message.add_reaction`

```py
await message.add_reaction(whatever)
```

3. You don't put events inside commands, you use `client.wait_for(event)`, here's an example

```py
@client.command()
async def voting(ctx, *text):
    # add the reactions to the message here or whatever

    # Here's how to wait for a reaction
    def check_reaction(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author

    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_reaction)

    # Here's how to wait for a message
    def check_message(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author

    message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check_message)
```

[`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: Ok thank you very much for this good explained answer :) I am new in python coding and don't know really much about it ...

Comment: no worries, remember to accept the answer if it helped